# Making Arrows Fly Faster [1.12]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a sniper with 1.12 commands. It's working very well (except for the fact that bows don't shoot perfectly) but I have a problem: arrow speed.

If you shoot an arrow at minimum speed, you can literally overtake the arrow and jump into it. That's not a very nice sniper -_- So I searched on internet and I only found one solution that blew up my world and is not survival friendly. So I'm asking you if you know anything to speed up an arrow (the arrows already have the tag of `{Nogravity:1b}`) you don't know in which direction the arrow is flying so I can't use the `Direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]` tag. I also tried `effect @e[type=arrow] 1 1 10` in a repeating command block.

I'm not a noob so you can trust me I didn't make [always active] mistakes or something.

*btw this is how it looks*
[image]

Comment: 1. A picture of command blocks doesn't tell us anything. 2. What did you try with that `effect` command? That's not how that command works. 3. What solution did you discard for blowing stuff up? It's likely that it can be changed to not do that. 4. Does it have to be 1.12? This becomes much easier in 1.13 (3x 2 not too complex commands). 5. Usually when someone feels the need to tell everybody that they're not a noob…

Comment: 1. no read the text the picture just gives you a little idea how it looks 2. I just tried it, the more information I give the better, isn't it? 3. Summoning tnt behind the arrow so the explosion speeds up the arrow. 4. Yes 1.12 pls 5. Otherwise I get useless commands about unimportant things, rlly don't think i'm fooling people, I'm pro with command blocks -_- idc what you think about me. I also make stupid mistakes, doesn't mean I'm a total beginner/noob...

Comment: 2. Since the command is completely wrong, it doesn't do anything. I am puzzled what you even thought it would do. 3. That sounds like a good idea, please give more detail. If you're already able to summon TNT so that it always appears behind the arrow, then you almost have a complete system already. 4. I don't really know how to effectively do it in 1.12. Btw, I was wrong, you only need 3 commands for 1.13, so it would be even better. 5. Everybody can forget something sometimes, so suggesting all possible solutions is better than forgetting the best one.

Comment: And since you apparently didn't even read the wiki for the effect command, you do not know all resources available to you. The wiki is a really good one, you should use it more. Also there's always more than learn, not knowing everything is not a shame.

Comment: What was the command for 1.13? You said it was done more easily in 1.13 (3 commands). I am working in 1.13 and faster arrows are really what I need for my project.

Answer (score -1):

Arrows being shot is unreliable due to RNG, you get this with bows and dispensers as you may know. However - given enough tnt, they're randomness will counter each other (for a tnt that will propel the arrow left, there is a tnt that will counter that and propel it right). making tnt highly accurate for projectiles. The arrow can be summoned in front of tnt and it's speed can be adjusted depending on how much tnt you use and the distance the arrow is to the tnt (the more tnt, the more accurate).

Comment: the only problem is that, TNT explodes  and does damage xD